# Which D3 Layout should I use to show relationships?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

Hi I'm just getting into Data Visualization and D3 and I'm trying to make a diagram that conveys the relationships between a group of people and I was wondering if I should use a Chord Diagram layout or a Hierarchal Bundling layout?

I like the look of the edges in Hierarchal Bundling layout but I really don't have an Hierarchy. Also Im not sure how the bundling works.

Can I make a chord layout in D3 with just strokes and not fills?

Comment: If you don't have a hierarchy then a hierarchical layout is unsuitable. And yes, you can make a chord layout without filling the chords.

Comment: Show us an example of your relationships.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of resources that can help you choose the right visualization technique for your data:

- [How to design Charts and Graphs](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/53/file-863940581-pdf/Data_Visualization_101_How_to_Design_Charts_and_Graphs.pdf)
- [Guide to Visual Communication](http://visage.co/downloads/Business_Guide_to_Visual_Communication_by_Visage.pdf)
- [Visualization Cheatseet by Tom MacWright](https://github.com/tmcw/visualization-cheatsheet)
- [A Tour through the Visualization Zoo by Jeffrey Heer, Michael Bostock, and Vadim Ogievetsky](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1805128)

Answer (score 1):

if you have number of people plototed against their attributes, then parallel plotting is the best option. In parallel Plotting you can compare the feature of 1 perso with another on the same chart.

Here are the two links that will help you in creating parallel coordinates:

1. [parallel chart 1 with all the capability making use of 1 library](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1341021)`
2. [`The famous chart directory blocks.org`](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1341021)